# Zf2 "The iterator class does not exist" on Session\Container definition

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

Sometimes on my website (ZendFramework2), I get an error when setting a session variable. 
The error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\\Stdlib\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The iterator class does not exist' in /MySite/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject/PhpReferenceCompatibility.php:374
Stack trace:
#0 /MySite/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject/PhpReferenceCompatibility.php(414): Zend\\Stdlib\\ArrayObject\\PhpReferenceCompatibility->setIteratorClass(NULL)
#1 [internal function]: Zend\\Stdlib\\ArrayObject\\PhpReferenceCompatibility->unserialize('a:4:{s:7:"stora...')
#2 /MySite/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Session/SessionManager.php(95): session_start()
#3 /MySite/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Session/AbstractContainer.php(78): Zend\\Session\\SessionManager->start()
#4 /MySite/module/Application/Module.php(97): Zend\\Session\\AbstractContainer->__construct('site')
#5 [internal function]: Application\\Module->onBootstrap(Object(Zend\\Mvc\\MvcEvent))
#6 /MySite/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject/PhpReferenceCompatibility.php on line 374
```

Code Module.php line 97 :

```
$s_site = new \Zend\Session\Container('site');
```

I try but I can not find why. Do you have any idea? Need more informations? 
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure how relevant it is, but `PhpReferenceCompatibility` class was removed in v2.3, maybe try updating to latest version of ZF2 and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: I tried to update the ZendFramework Version, but it's to long to adapt the app. I haven't the time..
Another idea?

Answer (score 0):

The is a result of the setIteratorClass method in ArrayObject/PhpReferenceCompatibility being passed a null $class argument.  I'm not sure why it sometimes gets a null, but the way I fixed it in my case was to set the iterator class as 'ArrayIterator' when passed a null object, like this:

```
if (!isset($class)) {
    $class = 'ArrayIterator';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest zf2 version, the `ArrayObject/PhpReferenceCompatibility` class has been removed, so please make the change in `stdlib/ArrayObject.php`.